# Trouble interfacing/communicating between Arduino Block and Intel Edison

Tags: python, arduino, mqtt, communication, intel-edison

I've been attempting to create a pretty large project, here are the main objectives:

- Connect 3+ sensors to Arduino block for Intel Edison
- Send the readings in some format to the Edison through UART?
- Have the Edison understand the received data, and publish it to an MQTT server

So far, the Edison is running the Paho-MQTT client in Python. I'm wondering what is the best way to have the Arduino block send its information to the Edison. If it sends info in string format, the Edison would have to unpack that string into a Python Dictionary to understand the data, before pushing to MQTT. This seems rather processor-intensive...

Another concern is communication between the Arduino and Edison. Does anyone have experience using this block? Sparkfun's website details the use of Firmata, but this is cumbersome. I would rather have the Arduino do it's own thing, and just hand off formatted values to the Edison.

All help is appreciated. Thanks.